# Did Scorsese know Nicholson would pull a real, unscripted gun on DiCaprio?

Tags: props, the-departed, martin-scorsese

After `05:20` in the video [Iconic Movie Scenes That Were Never Supposed To Happen](https://youtu.be/-IHzprfs6tw?t=319) the narrator says:

> In one scene, Nicholson totally surprised co-star Leonardo DiCaprio in the worst way. Nicholson had proposed the interaction to **Martin Scorsese, who allowed Nicholson to pull a real, unscripted gun on DiCaprio**, who reacted with genuine fear.

While surprising that a real, unscripted gun may have been used on the set of the [2006 film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Departed) and the director would have allowed this, Page Six's 2010 article [Scorsese ‘still gets chills’ over Nicholson pulling a gun on Leo DiCaprio while filming](https://pagesix.com/2010/11/29/scorsese-still-gets-chills-over-nicholson-pulling-a-gun-on-leo-dicaprio-while-filming/) says the opposite:

> When something wasn’t quite pushing it for Martin Scorsese while filming a pivotal scene in “The Departed,” Jack Nicholson unexpectedly pulled a real weapon on co-star Leonardo DiCaprio to bring the edge. “The first thing Jack did was sniff the glass and say, ‘I smell a rat’ . . . And then he pulled a gun on him,” Scorsese told Richard Schickel for his upcoming book, “Conversations With Scorsese.” **“He didn’t tell me he had a gun.** It was great . . . we took a lot out, but Leo’s reaction is real-time.” He said, “I still get chills,” when Nicholson says, “I smell a rat.” — “It’s so real to me.” Scorsese’s love of spontaneity started early.

**Question:** Did or did not Scorsese know that Nicholson would pull a real, unscripted gun on DiCaprio?

Has anything further been said in the intervening years after the 2010 Page Six article?

**Update:** Fandomwire.com's May 6, 2023 [Matt Damon And Leonardo DiCaprio Were Scared for Their Lives When Co-Star Pulled A Real Gun in $291M Martin Scorsese Film: “I still get chills”](https://fandomwire.com/matt-damon-and-leonardo-dicaprio-were-scared-for-their-lives-when-co-star-pulled-a-real-gun-in-291m-martin-scorsese-film-the-departed-i-still-get-chills/)
 recycles similar quotations, but points out that Richard Schnickel’s book [Conversations With Scorsese](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9800460-conversations-with-scorsese) is now published (actually in 2011) so a careful reading of the passage might inform us if Scorsese had some warning or not.

---

The scene where the gun is brandished:

Comment: I don't see a problem here. We have the directors own words saying he did not know over some random YouTube opinion. I know which I prefer. Frankly I don't see that this question can have a more definitive answer than the directors statement.

Comment: Haven't you ever stretched the truth a bit, just to make the story you are telling a bit more interesting? Both Scorsese or the person behind the youtube video could have improved the story a bit, just to make it worth listening to.

Comment: "allowed" doesn't necessarily mean Scorsese knew about it beforehand, it could also mean, that he allowed the scene to continue, despite not knowing about it. But I have a hard time believing that Scorsese wouldn't immediately stop everything when an actor suddenly pulls out a real gun. I have seen a few article saying it was a real gun, but they don't provide any proof of it, no quotes from Scorsese, DiCaprio or Nicholson or anyone else involved that say the gun was actually real.

Comment: @Paulie_D is it not possible that during the fourteen years since the film has been out that the director might have made *another statement* as well? Can we at least allow for that possibility? Could there not be other statements by *other people present* as well? Did we learn nothing from *Rashomon?*

Comment: Given what has happened with RUST, aren't all objects/props supposed to be inspected and/or cataloged before ever making it to set? It's one thing for a known gun to get misused, but it's another for unknown gun to be there at all, no??

Comment: @DarthLocke right, you've nicely articulated exactly what's been bothering me about this scenario. I'm guessing that it's got a substantial folklore/hype aspect to it